# Timer stops unexpectedly

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I was following the chnage notification example in
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications.

I had succesfully replicated it and deployed it to Azure.

But the timer function in the Get method of the Notification Controller stops getting triggered sometimes. Sometimes it happens just like that and sometimes after a fresh deployment of code to Azure.

Is there any work around or any alternative for the Timer class which is good for production app?

Comment: You should put the precise code sample that is problematic. Otherwise you ask everyone to do the investigation.

Comment: Maybe try setting the FA to "Always On".